# Which sender is captured inside Actor message handler?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm a novice to Akka actors, and I did some experiment as below to learn how actors work.

```scala
class RequestActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import RequestActor._
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(15.seconds)
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = context.dispatcher

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Request(name) =>
      // self ? TempRequest(TempRequest(name), xxx) pipeTo sender // Q1: if we reference `sender` here, which `sender` will be captured?
      self ? TempRequest(name, sender) onComplete {
        // val whichSender = sender  // Q2: if we reference `sender` here, which `sender` will be captured?
        case Success(TempResponse(msg, origin)) => origin ! HelloReply(msg)
        case Failure(ex) => ???
      }

    case TempRequest(name, origin) =>
      sender ! TempReply(s"hello, ${name}!", origin)

    case _ =>
      ???
  }
}
```

I understand we should prefer `tell` to `ask`. I made up this example trying to clear several confusions:

Q1 - Q2) I know `sender` is actually `context.sender()`. As the comment inside the code snippet, which `sender` will be captured?
My confusion is, will the `sender` be the right one resulting in the corresponding `ask` operation? Or could it be the `sender` of a message coming later?

3) Will actors be able to continue processing new messages while they're waiting for the reply  of the `ask`?
From the experiment, it seems so. Could anyone please confirm this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Whenver actor picks a message from the mailbox, the context is changed to according to new message, so `context.sender` starts pointing to the `sender` of this new message. And the `sender` method of actor just returns `context.sender`.

Comment: sender is a variable and after every context change, it will be re-assigned. So use a local variable to capture it before using it in a `ask` which is a Future and a new context will be in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> // self ? TempRequest(TempRequest(name), xxx) pipeTo sender // Q1: if we reference `sender` here, which `sender` will be captured?

The sender of message `Request`. This is not visible in your snippet.

From comment

> self ? TempRequest(TempRequest(name), xxx) pipeTo sender. As this is an ask and waiting will occur, before the response is received, another message could be received by the actor, and thus cause the sender to be change. So, isn't it possible that the pipeTo sender causes the response to send to a wrong actor?

`pipeTo` pattern will register a callback for the future returned by `?` or `ask` pattern. The callback will reference the sender returned by `sender()` at the time of callback registration, which is done in blocking manner when `Request` message is processed. Thus the `sender()` is the sender of `Request` message.

`pipeTo` excludes any possibility of actor context leakage and this is one of the reasons it should be used.

> // val whichSender = sender  // Q2: if we reference `sender` here, which `sender` will be captured?

This will actually cause a bug or leakage of actor context outside of an actor and must not be done. It can be done with a local reference like in following code

```
    case Request(name) =>
      val requestSender = context.sender()
      self ? TempRequest(name) onComplete {
        case Success(TempResponse(msg)) => requestSender ! HelloReply(msg)
      }
```

From [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html)

> When using future callbacks, such as onComplete, or map such as thenRun, or thenApply inside actors you need to carefully avoid closing over the containing actor’s reference, i.e. do not call methods or access mutable state on the enclosing actor from within the callback. This would break the actor encapsulation and may introduce synchronization bugs and race conditions because the callback will be scheduled concurrently to the enclosing actor. Unfortunately there is not yet a way to detect these illegal accesses at compile time.

And finally

> 3) Will actors be able to continue processing new messages while they're waiting for the reply of the ask?

Yes. There is no "waiting" process. It just registers a callback that is executed outside the actor. Thus the problem of possible actor context leakage.

Additionally,

You could use `forward` that preserves the original messages sender. And your code can be simplified as following

```
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case Request(name) =>
        self.forward(TempRequest(name))
      case TempRequest(name) =>
        sender() ! HelloReply(s"hello, ${name}!"))
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Ivan! Regarding Q2&Q3, I think I get your point. But for Q1, `self ? TempRequest(TempRequest(name), xxx) pipeTo sender`. As this is an `ask` and waiting will occur, before the response is generated, another message could be received by the actor, and thus cause the `sender` being changed. So, isn't it possible that the `pipeTo sender` causes the response to send to a wrong actor?

Comment: I see. The `def pipeTo(recipient: ActorRef)(...)` method will capture the current `sender` by a `val`, which is similar as your code example for the 2nd question.